# UISlider error XCode 7 Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to build a very simple app just to see how the UISlider works. I've seen several tutorials and followed them to the letter but nothing seems to work.

I keep getting this error exactly when I try to move the Slider in the simulator, after I've successfully built
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/96usz.png]

This is my whole code. It's really simple but I can't understand why the Slider won't work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var noteBottomLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderNoteBottom: UISlider!

@IBAction func changedSliderNoteBottom(sender: AnyObject) {
    var noteBottomValue = Int(sliderNoteBottom.value)
    noteBottomLabel.text = "\(noteBottomValue)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Can you see any problems with this? I'm probably noobing out, but I've looked everywhere and can't find an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import CoreFoundation



class ViewController2 : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
        @IBAction func slidervaluechanged(sender: UISlider) {
           print(Int(slider.value))

        }
}
```

I have tried your code just made the print of slider.value rather than putting it on label . 
But I have used Xcode 7.3  , I don't think this should be problem with Xcode .Use the sender as UISlider when making an @IBAction that looks better . Brings up the value of 0 at bottom and 1 at top.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sourav. I got a very similar (if not the same) error in a different project, and after some research I found what might have caused these errors.
Apparently, if you copy some code from inside a method (action) and paste it into another place of your code it may (or may not) also copy the connections the copied code has with UI elements. 

I might have copied some code around before I simplified the app, and that might be what's causing the error.